# Calling access named functions inside object literal

Tags: javascript

I want to call all functions defined inside of an object literal, but I can't seem to figure out how. functions will have to be named, so I can refer to them as `functions.function1();`

The structure is something like this:

```
var functions = {
    function1: function(){
        /* Important stuff */
    },
    function2: function(){
        /* Important stuff */
    }
    .
    .
    .
    functionN: function(){
        /* Imporant stuff */
    }
}
```

Variations of how I've tried to call them has been something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    functions[i].call()
}
```

but since `functions`doesn't have a length property, I can't call it like that.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!:-)

Comment: `functions` is a object and it doesn't have the property

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` and `forEach`

```
Object.keys( functions ).forEach( s => functions[s]() )
```

**Demo**

```js
var functions = {
    function1: function(){
       console.log(1);
    },
    function2: function(){
       console.log(2);
    },
    functionN: function(){
       console.log("n");
    }
};

Object.keys( functions ).forEach( s => functions[s]() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys of the object and call the functions accordingly. Following is an example:

```js
var functions = {
  function1: function() {
    console.log('func1');
  },
  function2: function() {
    console.log('func2');
  },
  functionN: function() {
    console.log('funcN');
  }
}

Object.keys(functions).forEach(f => functions[f].call());
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `for...in` loop to loop over object properties:

```
for (func in functions) {
    if (functions.hasOwnProperty(func)) {
        functions[func]();
    }
}
```